# What controller to use for 'dashboard' style UI which touches multiple domains

Tags: spring-mvc, grails, grails-controller

I'm vague about I should be using in a sort of a simulation app where the user is presented with a web page that presents data from multiple domains and provides a variety of interactions that touch multiple domains.

In this case it is a real estate simulation where the UI presentation shows the user data about houses, offer to buy and sell, status of the users negotiations, etc, information about "state of the world" and that kind of thing.  A fair amount of ajax going on in the page as well.

Can I just have a controller which is not associated with a particular domain and then just provide all the different objects?  Maybe use a command object to deal with actions coming back from the user?

Hopefully this quesiton is not too vague for a coherent answer, I'm just looking for suggestions on the high level approach.

Comment: You could even go further and create shared functionality this isn't a great example but gives you an idea https://github.com/vahidhedayati/jssh/blob/master/grails-app/controllers/grails/plugin/jssh/ConnectSshController.groovy#L306 which calls https://github.com/vahidhedayati/jssh/blob/master/grails-app/services/grails/plugin/jssh/j2ssh/JsshDbStorageService.groovy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can have a controller which does not directly correlate to a specific domain. For instance you could create a `DashboardController`. The use of command objects is up to you and your needs, but you can use Domain instance in the above controller just like any other controller.

Answer (score 1):

As @Joshua Moore stated, it's no problem, let me give a small - shortened - example. (hope it gives you a bit of an idea...)

I use in the application a bootstrap-theme and the information on the dashboard (several statistic widgets) is generated through ajax-calls into the dashboard-controller.

First, the UrlMappings.groovy file:

class UrlMappings {

```
static mappings = {
    "/$controller/$action?/$id?(.$format)?"{
        constraints {
            // apply constraints here
        }
    }

    "/"(controller: "dashboard", action:"index")
    "500"(view:'/error')
}
```

}

Then the controller-code:

```
package example

import java.util.Random
import grails.converters.JSON
import groovy.time.TimeCategory

class DashboardController {

    def index() {}

    def contractAmountAsJson() { ...someCode; return Data as JSON... }

}
```

Then the index.gsp page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="layout" content="main">
<g:set var="entityName" value="${message(code: 'syParameter.label', default: 'SyParameter')}" />
<title><g:message code="default.list.label" args="[entityName]" /></title>
</head>
<body>
<!-- NEW WIDGET START -->
<article class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
    <!-- Widget ID (each widget will need unique ID)-->
    <div class="jarviswidget" id="wid-id-8" data-widget-editbutton="false">
        <header>
            <span class="widget-icon"> <i class="fa fa-bar-chart-o"></i> </span>
            <h2>Vertragsvolumen aktiver Kunden-Verträge pro Monat</h2>
        </header>

        <!-- widget div-->
        <div>
            <!-- widget edit box -->
            <div class="jarviswidget-editbox">
                <!-- This area used as dropdown edit box -->
            </div>
            <!-- end widget edit box -->

            <!-- widget content -->
            <div class="widget-body no-padding">
                <div id="customerContractAmount" class="chart no-padding"></div>
            </div>
            <!-- end widget content -->
        </div>
        <!-- end widget div -->
    </div>
    <!-- end widget -->
</article>
</body>
</html>
```

And the javascript as an example:

```
if ($('#customerContractAmount').length) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '${request.contextPath}/dashboard/contractAmountAsJson?type=customer',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(chartData) {
            Morris.${session?.user?.statisticStyle ? session.user.statisticStyle : "Area"}({
                element : 'customerContractAmount',
                data : chartData,
                xkey : 'period',
                ykeys : ['a', 'b', 'c'],
                labels : ['bestätigt', 'erstellt', 'in Arbeit']
            });
        }
    });
}
```